# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ComplexElement' and 'int'

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I want to solve an ODE and face this error.

What am I doing wrong? How can I do this correctly?

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import integrate
import numpy as np

s = 1*10**-4
E0 = 8.8541878128*(10**-12)
d1 = 500*(10**-6)
E1 = 2
d0 = d1/E1
v = 0.2
e = 2.7*10**-5
R = 1 
t = sp.Symbol('t')
Q = sp.Function('Q')(t)
diff_eq = sp.Eq(Q.diff(t), ((e*v*t/E0)-((Q*(d0+v*t))/(s*E0))))
sol1 = sp.dsolve(diff_eq, Q, x0=0)
```

Comment: When asking about an error, show the full **traceback**.  And with `sympy`, I like to see the display of some intermediate values, such as `diff_eq`.

Comment: hello thank you but i solve this ODE by scipy just i want so solve that by sympy to take derivative from that

Comment: It ran for me (no error), but the result had some unevaluated integrals.

Comment: i run that it colab is it possible the colab have problem?

Comment: Can you send me the same integral? i really need that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code with Python `3.8.6`, numpy `1.22.4` and sympy `1.10.1`. Perhaps, you can also share the versions as well.

Comment: hello mario i was runing on colab my python an jupyter did not run this an just pass from that whithout any reaction

Comment: thank you so much i change my python to s.8.6 and get answer